# Not able to read data from contact sensor - gazebo 7

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have created a world in gazebo and I have added a contact sensor to it. in gazebo 2 it was working, but in gazebo 7 is not working using the same code.
This is my code using ros indigo and gazebo 7.

0.2
      0.2
      true
      Gazebo/Red
      
    sensor_link_geom --> 
        true
        100
        
          fsensor_link_collision
        
        
          fsensor_link_sensor_state
          fsensor_link

thank you,
Giovanni

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240563/not-able-to-read-data-from-contact-sensor---gazebo-7/) by [giovadema85](https://answers.ros.org/users/27625/giovadema85/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-07-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found what I think could be considered a quick fix but this isn't pretty :

You will need to add  "_collision" between the collision name which is inside the link ( without it ) and the one inside the gazebo flag ( with it ).

This may not be enough, you may have to add the link name and some other info too... So i invite you to go in the link just below to have a more detailed answer : http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15095/gazebo-contact-sensor-added-to-a-robot-link-in-urdf-file-is-not-working-as-expected/?answer=15243#post-id-15243

Anyway I made it work so if you ned help just ask and i will try my best to help you

TTDM

---

Originally posted by [TTDM](https://answers.ros.org/users/28649/ttdm/) with karma: 267 on 2017-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0